# How do I show my Outlook calendar in the agenda section of the date and time pop-up in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

When I click on the date and time (bottom right) in Windows 10, I see a pop-up with the calendar for the month and a "show agenda" option. When I click on this, I'm told that I have no events.

[image]

Given that I'm using Office 356, is there any way I can get the contents of my Outlook calendar to be displayed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add your account in Windows Calendar, then the calendar items of your account will be synced and shown when you click "show agenda" otion:

1.Search **Calendar** in windows search bar.

2.Click **Menu** icon>click **Settings** icon>click Manage Accounts:

[image]

3.Click **Add Account**:

[image]

After adding your account successfully, wait for a moment and then the calendar items will be displayed as shown in the below figure:

[image]